# ReactJS ProtectedRoute redirects. Variable rendered twice, false on the first time yet its true in the redux-store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Am trying to implement the ProtectedRoute. But when i pass authentication, meaning am authenticated rightly from the auth API, get my token, i get pushed to the main page without a problem.
However, when i type in the browser the URL manually to the protected route, i get redirected to the Login page.

Am storing the isAuthenticated flag in a redux store using redux-toolkit. Check out my code below

**ProtectedRoute.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const ProtectedRoute = ( { component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
    const [ isAuthed, setAuthed ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAuthed(isLoggedIn);
    }, [isLoggedIn]);


    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest}
               render={
                  props => (
                    isAuthed === true
                      ? <Component {...props} />
                      : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location} }}/>
                )
            }
      />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

The composition of the App.js are as follows

```
      <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/main" component={ Dashboard } />
                <Route path="*">
                  <div>404 Not found</div>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

I tried passing this login as a prop from the **App.js** to the **ProtectedRoute** but still i cant get the result i want.

What i realized though is that there's double rendering. On the first time, reading the **isLoggedIn** variable produces a false result and therefore forces a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing URL manually or copying the URL to another tab destroys the OLD state. This happens when we try to get our state from redux Store using useSelector.
I solved it by using backend code and providing ***expiry time*** for each user logged in and than linked that user with store's State.
To check if ***user's time*** is expired or not i used npm package Decode and this small code.

```
 const token = user?.token;  //this user is srored in localstorage
   // JWT..
   if (token) {
     const decodedToken = decode(token);

     if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) logout(i); //here is what you    
                                                                   // need at frontend
   }
   setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));
```